# Working of subquery in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I was trying to understand how nested or nested subqueries work in Oracle when dealing with SQL. So lets take an example where I have 2 tables, one where I hold all student information and one where I hold all the grades each student has received. Now I'm trying to find all students that received at least one 'A' grade form the grades table. I can do a simple join and get the output for this. But the problem is if a student has received an 'A' grade twice, his ID shows up twice. Now I know I can use the DISTINCT word to solve my problem. But I wanted to do this using nested queries and so this is what I typed -> 
select id from students where id in (select id from grades); 
Now this query returns an output with no duplicates. I'm trying to get my head around this and how this nested query works in detail. What does the "where in" part also do? Really confused.

Comment: (1) I removed the inappropriate database tags.  (2) You should edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not universally true that a `distinct` is a bad thing, it is often misused -- and I think your example is a good one where there is a better way.

In this case, I think your best bet is a semi-join.  Here is a rough example:

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (
  select null
  from grades g
  where
    s.student_id = g.student_id and
    g.grade = 'A'
)
```

Oracle does a pretty nice job of executing a subquery into a semi-join in the background, when it makes sense, but other DBMSs definitely benefit from this construct.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for your response! I now understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the way it works is a join and a distinct - but Oracle is smart, it does it efficiently. It does what you would do: it takes the first student_id from the first table, and it tries to match it against rows in the second table. But, since you don't need the whole join, it will stop as soon as it finds a match - then it moves on to the second row in the first table.

I assume you meant the subquery to be `select id from grades where grade = 'A'`, right?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for your response! I now understand :)